# Best practice for using Firebase database to store invitations

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following case:

User got invitation ticket, after they invite person, the number will decrease. The user can't add the invitation number by their own. Based on the Firebase (Within Function), it seems that it is not suitable for this use case, because once I grant access for user to modify the invitation number for user, they can somehow increase the number or assign any number they want. Is my understand correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, security rules can allow you to restrict the data written to the realtime database and by whom.

If you need trusted administrative logic, such as keeping counters you can use Cloud Functions for Firebase or the admin-sdk on a traditional backend.